# What is the best choice for ing , to infinitive or ing

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> - the justification given **for explaining**  his action is unbelievable!
> - the justification given **to explain**  his action is unbelievable!
> - the justification given, **explaining**  his action is unbelievable!

what is the best

I think the first one is the best because the justification  was not the goal of his act  not like  Joe wrote a book to share his experiences more than joe got acclaims for writing a book and the action is already finished

Comment: Will you please edit the question and explain which one do you consider to be best, and why? And why are the others "not best"? Right now, your question looks like you want us to solve your homework, and we do not do that here.

Comment: no it is not to solve my homework

Comment: All three examples mean slightly different things ... As usual, we need a bit more context to know which one fits best, and/or to adjust to fit. (Particularly No.2)

Comment: what are the differences

Comment: there is no context, it is a sentence that I have imagined